# Select permisos de un usuario MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

He intentado con:

```
select user,host,select_priv from user
where user = ´visitante´;
```

Pero la informacion no es muy clara y no da los resultados que deberia dar. Se la existencia de la comanda `show grants` pero no lo puedo utilizar.

El resultado que quiero que del `select` son los permisos de dicho usuario.

Comment: no se entiende la pregunta, que deseas lograr obtener?

Comment: Deseo obtener los permisos de dicho usuario.

Comment: por que no puedes usar 'SHOW GRANTS'?

Comment: Porque el professor dijo que no podiamos usar show grants.

Comment: Pues dile a tu profesor que "prohibir" funciones, es como mandarte a caminar sin zapatos.

Comment: @Youshiro a veces no es eso. A veces se busca que uno conozca lo que pasa dentro del sistema para poder entender mejor sus funciones. En general las DB guardan toda la informacion en tablas, como buenas DB que son.. Entonces no es ilogico pedir que se pueda rastrear esa información de esa forma. Es una forma de aprender lo que realmente hace el sistema.

Comment: Lo que si te pediria pepe, es que nos digas que parte de la informacion no fue clara, y que resultados estas esperando obtener.

Comment: el select_priv entiendo que es si el usuario tiene permisos de select, el resultado obtenido es N, pero deberia dar Y de yes ya que el usuario puede hacer select en una table especifica en un campo especifico. Y que diga Y o N en general tambien es un problema ya que necesitas saber que tabla o que campo sesta tratando pero el problema es que tendrias que hacer select por cada tabla, cada campo, cada BD en un solo select de esta forma no lo puedes obtener.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se me ocurre que saques los permisos de la tabla `mysql.user` de este modo

```
SELECT user, Select_priv, Insert_priv, Update_priv, Delete_priv
FROM mysql.user
WHERE User = "tuUsuario";
```

Dándote un resultado similar al siguiente

```
+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| user      | Select_priv | Insert_priv | Update_priv | Delete_priv |
+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| tuUsuario | Y           | Y           | Y           | Y           |
+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)
```

Los permisos se guardan en un campo de tipo `ENUM` con valores por defecto como YES o NO dependiendo si tiene esos permisos asignados

Yo solo coloque algunos datos de referencia, pero si haces un

```
DESCRIBE mysql.user;
```

Veras un resultado similar al siguiente, de donde tu puedes elegir que otros valores deseas conocer para la cuenta de un usuario en específico

```
MySQL [(none)]> DESCRIBE mysql.user;
+--------------------------+-----------------------------------+------+-----+---------------
--------+-------+
| Field                    | Type                              | Null | Key | Default
        | Extra |
+--------------------------+-----------------------------------+------+-----+---------------
--------+-------+
| Host                     | char(60)                          | NO   | PRI |
        |       |
| User                     | char(32)                          | NO   | PRI |
        |       |
| Select_priv              | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N
        |       |
| Insert_priv              | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N
        |       |
| Update_priv              | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N
        |       |
| Delete_priv              | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N
        |       |
| Create_priv              | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N
        |       |
| Drop_priv                | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N
        |       |
| Reload_priv              | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N
        |       |
| Shutdown_priv            | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N
        |       |
| Process_priv             | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N
        |       |
| File_priv                | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N
        |       |
| Grant_priv               | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N
        |       |
| References_priv          | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N
        |       |
| Index_priv               | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N
        |       |
| Alter_priv               | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N
        |       |
| Show_db_priv             | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N
        |       |
| Super_priv               | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N
        |       |
| Create_tmp_table_priv    | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N
        |       |
| Lock_tables_priv         | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N
        |       |
| Execute_priv             | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N
        |       |
| Repl_slave_priv          | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N
        |       |
| Repl_client_priv         | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N
        |       |
| Create_view_priv         | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N
        |       |
| Show_view_priv           | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N
        |       |
| Create_routine_priv      | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N
        |       |
| Alter_routine_priv       | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N
        |       |
| Create_user_priv         | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N
        |       |
| Event_priv               | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N
        |       |
| Trigger_priv             | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N
        |       |
| Create_tablespace_priv   | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N
        |       |
| ssl_type                 | enum('','ANY','X509','SPECIFIED') | NO   |     |
        |       |
| ssl_cipher               | blob                              | NO   |     | NULL
        |       |
| x509_issuer              | blob                              | NO   |     | NULL
        |       |
| x509_subject             | blob                              | NO   |     | NULL
        |       |
| max_questions            | int(11) unsigned                  | NO   |     | 0
        |       |
| max_updates              | int(11) unsigned                  | NO   |     | 0
        |       |
| max_connections          | int(11) unsigned                  | NO   |     | 0
        |       |
| max_user_connections     | int(11) unsigned                  | NO   |     | 0
        |       |
| plugin                   | char(64)                          | NO   |     | caching_sha2_p
assword |       |
| authentication_string    | text                              | YES  |     | NULL
        |       |
| password_expired         | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N
        |       |
| password_last_changed    | timestamp                         | YES  |     | NULL
        |       |
| password_lifetime        | smallint(5) unsigned              | YES  |     | NULL
        |       |
| account_locked           | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N
        |       |
| Create_role_priv         | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N
        |       |
| Drop_role_priv           | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N
        |       |
| Password_reuse_history   | smallint(5) unsigned              | YES  |     | NULL
        |       |
| Password_reuse_time      | smallint(5) unsigned              | YES  |     | NULL
        |       |
| Password_require_current | enum('N','Y')                     | YES  |     | NULL
        |       |
| User_attributes          | json                              | YES  |     | NULL
        |       |
+--------------------------+-----------------------------------+------+-----+---------------
--------+-------+
51 rows in set (0.006 sec)
```

Y te vas a concentrar para lo que buscas en las columnas

- `Select_priv`
- `Insert_priv`
- `Delete_priv`
- `Update_priv`

No olvides al final agregar el

```
WHERE User = "tuUsuario"
```

Para que te muestre que tipo de privilegios tiene tu usuario en específico

Aquí te dejo la [dcoumentación oficial](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant-tables.html) para que consultes mas sobre lo que contiene la tabla antes mencionada